# c++ Functions (with body) as Argument

Tags: c++, function, argument-passing

I want to pass an function as argument. I know you can pass a function pointer like the first test in my example, but is it possible to pass a hold function (not a pointer) like my second test?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


/* variable for function pointer */
void (*func)(int);

/* default output function */
void my_default(int x) {
    cout << "x =" << "\t" << x << endl << endl;
}


/* entry */
int main() {
    cout << "Test Programm\n\n";

    /* 1. Test - default output function */
    cout << "my_default\n";
    func = &my_default;   // WORK! OK!
    func(5);

    /* 2. Test - special output function 2 */
    cout << "my_func2\n";
    func =  void my_func1(int x) {
            cout << "x =" << "  " << x << endl << endl;
        };   // WON'T WORK! FAILED!
    func(5);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you can pass a lambda with templates

Comment: Maybe what you are seeking is a functor? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/356950/c-functors-and-their-uses

Comment: Have a look at the following: [lambdas](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda), [std::bind](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind), [std::function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function). These allow you to pass functions as parameters (define your interfaces to receive them, late-bind arguments and pass-by-value/reference/pointer).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In C++ 11, you can pass a lambda:

```
func = [](int x) {  cout << "x =" << "  " << x << endl << endl; };
```

EDIT: lambdas can return values:

```
func = [](int x)->int{  cout << "x =" << "  " << x << endl << endl; return x; };
```

Comment: thank that's great. But what about functions with return values?

Comment: @Heinrich lambdas can return values

Comment: @Heinrich you'd write `[](int x) -> int {  cout << "x =" << "  " << x << endl << endl; return x; };

Comment: I see the return value is not important.

Comment: And lambdas consisting of just a return statement can omit the `-> type` to make it even simpler: `[](int x) { return x*x; }`

Answer (score 1):

With c++11, you can write such code in a lot simpler way:

Instead of writing function signature use `auto`

```
auto func = &my_default;   // WORK! OK!
func(5);
```

you can also use std::function objects to pass them around:

```
template<typename T>
void callme(std::function<T> f) {
   f(6);
}
std::function<decltype(my_default)> func1 = &my_default;
func(5);
callme(func1);
```

and also you can use lambdas:

```
/* 2. Test - special output function 2 */
cout << "my_func2\n";
auto fun = [](int x) {
        cout << "x =" << "  " << x << endl << endl;
    };  
fun(5);
```

Comment: that was OP comment, removed it

Comment: Ah didn't see it my bad!

Answer (score 0):

You can uses lamdas:

```
  std::function<int(int)> func2 = [](int i) { return i+4; };
  std::cout << "func2: " << func2(6) << '\n';
```

> if the body consists of the single return statement, the return type
>   is the type of the returned expression (after rvalue-to-lvalue,
>   array-to-pointer, or function-to-pointer implicit conversion)

If you lamda constains not single return statamen you should specify `return type`

```
 std::function<int(int)> func2 = [=](int i) ->int {
                                                   if (globalVar)
                                                     return i*4;
                                                   else 
                                                     return 4;
                                                  };
 std::cout << "func2: " << func2(6) << '\n';
```

Answer (score 0):

Even with return value it work:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


/* variable for function pointer */
int (*func)(int);

/* default output function */
int my_default(int x) {
    //cout << "x =" << "\t" << x << endl << endl;
    return x;
}


/* entry */
int main() {
    cout << "Test Programm\n\n";

    /* 1. Test - default output function */
    cout << "my_default\n";
    func = &my_default;   // WORK! OK!
    cout << func(5) << endl << endl;

    /* 2. Test - special output function 2 */
    cout << "my_func2\n";
    func =  [](int x) {
            //cout << "x =" << "  " << x << endl << endl;
            return x;
        };
    cout << func(5) << endl << endl;

    return 0;
}
```